# Assert that list should not have the string

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I have a assertion like this:

```
validationResults.Select(result => result.Tag).ToList().Should().Contain(ServiceContractRuleKey.MedicalDeclarationNumberRequired "because a validation error should be added that the MedicalDeclarationNumber is missing.");
```

How can i make it to assert that the validationResults should not contain the `'ServiceContractRuleKey.MedicalDeclarationNumberRequired'` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind to post the unit testing framework at least? My crystal ball is still under repair.

Comment: @nvoigt FluentAssertions I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NotContain method:

```
validationResults.Select(result => result.Tag)
                 .ToList()
                 .Should()
                 .NotContain(ServiceContractRuleKey.MedicalDeclarationNumberRequired);
```

You can also pass a predicate to NotContain method and simplify your code:

```
validationResults.Should()
                 .NotContain(item => item.Tag == ServiceContractRuleKey.MedicalDeclarationNumberRequired);
```